# Advanced traceroute tool for Linux

Tags: linux

Is there comparable alternative for PingPlotter Pro on Linux? I'm looking for traceroute tool that has ability to display traceroute data of each nodes along the route in nice timeline graph.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

How about [MTR](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/)?

```
# mtr -r serverfault.com
HOST: gentoo                      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.0.1                0.0%    10    0.9   1.2   0.9   1.6   0.3
  2.|-- 192.168.1.1                0.0%    10    1.9   2.2   1.6   4.1   0.7
  3.|-- localhost                 20.0%    10   28.3  48.5   6.5  98.6  30.0
    |  `|-- 216.187.120.226
    |   |-- 202.97.50.42
    |   |-- 216.187.124.122
  4.|-- 202.97.52.42               0.0%    10    3.8 135.3   3.8 976.8 298.2
    |  `|-- 222.252.96.97
    |   |-- 216.187.124.118
    |   |-- 216.187.115.37
    |   |-- 216.187.115.221
    |   |-- 216.187.124.122
    |   |-- 216.187.120.226
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do it. I need something that allows me to see the recorded traceroute data in timeline graph

Answer (score 3):

Smokeping, make even nicer graphs than PingPlotter.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping-demo/?target=Customers.OP

http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/

Comment: I'm trying to find the same thing as Flint... just set up smokeping, and it's close, but like Flint I'm also looking for info on the individual hops, not just the end result.  Basically a hybrid between MTR and smokeping.

Answer (score 0):

RRDtool and a custom packet ping script should be perfect (traceroute being ping with incrementing TTL times). I used to have one I crafted up in a few minutes time to track ping times to a server over the course of the day.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrdtutorial.en.html covers most of what you need to know.